# How can we have Gradient Color background in alert dialog box and a fixed Width

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient, flutter-layout

I tried using

> backgroundColor

but gradient color I need

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
    title: Text("Verify",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    content: Text("You have successfully verified your mobile number",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  );

   showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

I need backgroundColor to be gradient of color #4a00e0 to #8e2de2 in linear direction

Comment: there is no such thing like `background-color` in flutter: it is not css  - what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: backgroundColor, my bad

Comment: AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,

Comment: I accepted the answer, so I edited to solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply gradient on Material Dialog is weirdest idea but if it's really needed
i think the best option is copy-paste dialog.dart code into custom class and modify it

so the result, you can pass any gradients
[image]

how to use example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/weird_alert_dialog.dart' show UnicornAlertDialog;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AppBar')),
        body: Content(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _showDialod(context),
        child: Text('PRESS ME'),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showDialod(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return UnicornAlertDialog(
          title: Text('Title'),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.purpleAccent, Colors.blue],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(child: Text('Action 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)), onPressed: () {}),
            FlatButton(child: Text('Action 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)), onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and modified AlertDialog class itself
nothing special is here, I just removed all comments from file and a bit modified it - pass gradient as parameter and wrap dialog child widget with Container with gradient decoration

**weird_alert_dialog.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dialog({
    Key key,
    this.gradient,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.insetAnimationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    this.insetAnimationCurve = Curves.decelerate,
    this.shape,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double elevation;
  final Duration insetAnimationDuration;
  final Curve insetAnimationCurve;
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final Widget child;
  final Gradient gradient;

  static const RoundedRectangleBorder _defaultDialogShape =
      RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)));
  static const double _defaultElevation = 24.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
    return AnimatedPadding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets + const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0),
      duration: insetAnimationDuration,
      curve: insetAnimationCurve,
      child: MediaQuery.removeViewInsets(
        removeLeft: true,
        removeTop: true,
        removeRight: true,
        removeBottom: true,
        context: context,
        child: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),
            child: Material(
              color: backgroundColor ?? dialogTheme.backgroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
              elevation: elevation ?? dialogTheme.elevation ?? _defaultElevation,
              shape: shape ?? dialogTheme.shape ?? _defaultDialogShape,
              type: MaterialType.card,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: _defaultDialogShape.borderRadius,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: gradient
                  ),
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnicornAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnicornAlertDialog({
    Key key,
    @required this.gradient,
    this.title,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.titleTextStyle,
    this.content,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0),
    this.contentTextStyle,
    this.actions,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.shape,
  })  : assert(contentPadding != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Gradient gradient;
  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final TextStyle titleTextStyle;
  final Widget content;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final TextStyle contentTextStyle;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double elevation;
  final String semanticLabel;
  final ShapeBorder shape;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    String label = semanticLabel;

    if (title != null) {
      children.add(Padding(
        padding: titlePadding ?? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, content == null ? 20.0 : 0.0),
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: titleTextStyle ?? dialogTheme.titleTextStyle ?? theme.textTheme.title,
          child: Semantics(
            child: title,
            namesRoute: true,
            container: true,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
          label = semanticLabel;
          break;
        case TargetPlatform.android:
        case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
          label = semanticLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.alertDialogLabel;
      }
    }

    if (content != null) {
      children.add(Flexible(
        child: Padding(
          padding: contentPadding,
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: contentTextStyle ?? dialogTheme.contentTextStyle ?? theme.textTheme.subhead,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if (actions != null) {
      children.add(ButtonTheme.bar(
        child: ButtonBar(
          children: actions,
        ),
      ));
    }

    Widget dialogChild = IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: children,
      ),
    );

    if (label != null)
      dialogChild = Semantics(
        namesRoute: true,
        label: label,
        child: dialogChild,
      );

    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      gradient: gradient,
      elevation: elevation,
      shape: shape,
      child: dialogChild,
    );
  }
}

class SimpleDialogOption extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleDialogOption({
    Key key,
    this.onPressed,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 24.0),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SimpleDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleDialog({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.gradient,
    this.titlePadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 0.0),
    this.children,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 16.0),
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.shape,
  })  : assert(titlePadding != null),
        assert(contentPadding != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double elevation;
  final String semanticLabel;
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    final List<Widget> body = <Widget>[];
    String label = semanticLabel;

    if (title != null) {
      body.add(Padding(
        padding: titlePadding,
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          child: Semantics(namesRoute: true, child: title),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
          label = semanticLabel;
          break;
        case TargetPlatform.android:
        case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
          label = semanticLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.dialogLabel;
      }
    }

    if (children != null) {
      body.add(Flexible(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: contentPadding,
          child: ListBody(children: children),
        ),
      ));
    }

    Widget dialogChild = IntrinsicWidth(
      stepWidth: 56.0,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: body,
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (label != null)
      dialogChild = Semantics(
        namesRoute: true,
        label: label,
        child: dialogChild,
      );
    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      gradient: gradient,
      elevation: elevation,
      shape: shape,
      child: dialogChild,
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildMaterialDialogTransitions(
    BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
  return FadeTransition(
    opacity: CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animation,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}

Future<T> showDialog<T>({
  @required
      BuildContext context,
  bool barrierDismissible = true,
  @Deprecated('Instead of using the "child" argument, return the child from a closure '
      'provided to the "builder" argument. This will ensure that the BuildContext '
      'is appropriate for widgets built in the dialog.')
      Widget child,
  WidgetBuilder builder,
}) {
  assert(child == null || builder == null);
  assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));

  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
  return showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      final Widget pageChild = child ?? Builder(builder: builder);
      return SafeArea(
        child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return theme != null ? Theme(data: theme, child: pageChild) : pageChild;
        }),
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
    barrierColor: Colors.black54,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    transitionBuilder: _buildMaterialDialogTransitions,
  );
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add something in Pubspec.yaml file to load wierd_alert_dialog.dart?

Comment: no, just create file `wierd_alert_dialog.dart` and copy-paste the code

Comment: Actually I need to see the alert box, after verification of user, so I there any way I can do it in the same file

Comment: look at my example, there are two separate files - one of them is custom dialog class, to import it i use `import 'package:flutter_app/weird_alert_dialog.dart' show UnicornAlertDialog;` so you code will clear, I don't know how to explain

Comment: Where shoud i add this file Unicorn Alert Dialog , if you can help

Comment: i split code into two parts, the first one is an example, you can see how to import class and use it, second part is a bunch of classes should be put into weird_alert_dialog.dart file

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Dialog(
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient:LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.red,
                        Colors.blue
                      ]
                    )
                  ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(title: Text("Title")),
                        ListTile(title: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.")),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: () {},),
                            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.done), onPressed: () {},),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I do something like this in Alert Dialog code @Doc

Comment: Doable but not worth it. Too ugly to look at !! see edit

Comment: I used it but I got floatingactionbutton undefined

Comment: can you post your complete code? I have tested this code before posting.

Comment: I am done with it, I used the above solution by the way thanks for helping